# How to create nested cells inside the same table TD

Tags: html, razor

I have the following table:-

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var permisionMag in Model.PermisionManagement)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@permisionMag.Name</td>
                @{
                    int i = 0;
                    <td class="f">
                        @foreach(var item in permisionMag.TechnologyTypes.OrderBy(a => a.Name)) {
                            @(i+1)  @item.Name  
                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                        <br />           
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But currently i need the second column to have nested rows instead of showing the rows inside the same TD? any advice on this?

Comment: Where exactly do you want the nested rows? Can you provide some generic HTML that is set up the way you want your actual code to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rowspan on the first column  :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>@foreach(var permisionMag in Model.PermisionManagement) {
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="@permisionMag.TechnologyTypes.Count()">@permisionMag.Name</td>
            @{
             int i = 0;
             foreach (var item in permisionMag.TechnologyTypes.OrderBy(a => a.Name))
             { 

                i = i + 1;
                if( i > 1) {
                   </tr><tr>
                }
                <td class="f">
                     @(i+1)  @item.Name  
                </td>
              }
            }
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[See expecting result](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq6NN/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: i tired the above but did not work the rows will be nested inside each others.

Answer (score 1):

You can not generate directly table cells, you have to generate a new table inside the second table cell.
You could also render `@item.Name` as a span/div and style that to create the illusion of a nested table([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jxPYF/)).

Comment: i have created a table inside the original table , and it gave me almost what i need ..

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, then you probably want to do this:

```
@foreach(var permisionMag in Model.PermisionManagement) {
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="@permisionMag.TechnologyTypes.Count()">@permisionMag.Name</td>

    @{int i = 0;
    @foreach (var item in permisionMag.TechnologyTypes.OrderBy(a => a.Name)) {
        <td class="f">
            @(i+1)  @item.Name
            i = i + 1;
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        }
    </tr>
    }
}
```

But it should essentially build you something like this:

```
----------------
| Name | Item1 |
|      | ----- |
|      | Item2 |
|      | ----- |
|      | Item3 |
|      | ----- |
|      | Item4 |
----------------
```

Comment: Hah! You're correct - I forgot my TRs. Update the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KJ3m/1/ and updating the code now

Comment: I think that's typo free... :)